Not able to uninstall package
I'am not able to uninstall a managed package from an org. I am getting the following messages :

I have already checked with the button "where is this used?" and tried with VS Code by downloading all metadata and doing a text search to find any reference to those custom fields or the mentioned components like "Candidate_76262e22_f36d_4d14_9171_24f2c9cb874d". I have also tried with a tool named "Salto" but without success.
I am at my wits end and any suggestion will be welcomed.
Just to add some context:

Those custom fields are under the standard "Contact" object
Candidate is a record type for the object "Contact", I don't know if this can be related
When I click any of the hyperlinks, I get a page with "This page isn't available in Salesforce Lightning Experience or mobile app." in LEX and "You do not have the level of access necessary to perform the operation you requested." when I'm on classic.
The hyperlink apparently points to some metadata with Id "0gaAa00000003sL" for example. I tried to look for an object with prefix "0ga" in the org but didn't find anything.


Do you have inactive flow versions that might use components from the managed package?

@PhilW that sounds right, but then, doesn't "Where is the Used" show inactive flows?
thedja What happens when you click on the Candidate hyperlink?

@PhilW No components is used in our custom flows, and if they were we should be able to find reference to them with VS code or Salto.

@DavidCheng Sorry I forgot to add those details. I have updated the question !

I was talking about previous versions of flows. But if you are confident this is not relevant, fair enough.

@THEDJA You should open a case with Salesforce.

@DavidCheng I opened a ticket with the package vendor, if nothing there, I will open one with Salesforce

After opening a ticket with SF support, we found that the dependencies were in the Einstein Prediction Builder, some prediction was based on all Contact fields and since it was developed by another team, I was missing the context to identify the issue and also the permission to following the hyperlink provided in the error message.
For future reference, the following website is helpful to have a list of all Salesforce objects prefixes, in occurrence the object record "0gaAa00000003sL" is related to the object "MLDataDefinition" used by Einstein Prediction Builder.
Hope this helps other people !

Try deleting the record type and then try to uninstall the package again.  If those errors go away, you may be done but sometimes it's an iterative process where you don't get them all the first time.

It's not that simple to delete a record type which is in production.
